# jQuery ajax form file upload to .Net MVC with InsertionMode.Replace only working once

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload, jquery-forms-plugin

I followed an example from the following url that shows how to use the jQuery Form plugin to do an async file upload to my .NET MVC controller.  ( http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/ ) Everything works completely great the first time and after I upload a file the first time I am replacing the div inside which the form sits via a returned PartialView.  When the div is replaced I then call a javascript function to rebuild the ajaxForm object but that seems to be where things stop working.  When the code returns the first time I get my replaced div just fine and the appearance is proper, but the javascript code does not seem to be attaching the ajaxForm object back to the form that exists inside the replaced div.  This means that the second time I post with the form, it redirects the user away from the page. I would love to say it's a caching issue in the controller, but the response I get shows the updated list of items in the ascx. One last thing, when I look at the dom element in the IE dev toolbar I see an attribute like "jQuery16404440065521567182" with a value of 33 and that disappears after the first submit. I'm guessing that is put there by the ajaxForm. Here is the code I am using ( some of the javascript namespacing was changed to remove project specific naming ):

ASCX file

```
 <!-- Form to add a new record -->
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAttachment", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "AttachmentForm" })) { %>
<input type="hidden" name="ReportId" value="<%: Model.ReportId %>" />
<input type="file" name="FileUpload" value="" size="21" />
<label for="Title">
    Title:</label>
<input type="text" name="Title" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Add" class="inputButton" />
<% } %>

<!-- Display existing items -->
    <% foreach (var item in Model.ExistingAttachments) {  %>
<div>
    <%: item.Sort %>&nbsp;<%: item.Title.PadRight(25, ' ').Substring(0, 25).TrimEnd() %></div>
<% } %>
```

ASPX file

```
<div id="AttachmentsWindow">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("LoadAttachments", Model.ReportAttachments); %>
</div>

<!-- This form is used to refresh the above div -->
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("LoadAttachments", new { ReportId = Model.ReportId },
           new AjaxOptions {
               HttpMethod = "Post",
               LoadingElementId = "LoadingAttachments",
               UpdateTargetId = "AttachmentsWindow",
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               OnComplete = "Report.InitAttachment"
           }, new { id = "LoadAttachmentsForm" })) { %>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="button" style="float:right;"
    onmouseover="this.className='button buttonhov'" onmouseout="this.className='button'"/>
    <% } %>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public FileUploadJsonResult SaveAttachment(ReportAttachmentViewModel Attachment) {

        if ( Attachment.FileUpload.ContentLength < 1 ){
            return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { message = "No file chosen." } };
        }

        var Report = this._reportRepository.GetById(Attachment.ReportId);

        if (Report == null)
            throw new Exception("Report not found");


        MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
        Attachment.FileUpload.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
        byte[] data = target.ToArray();


        ReportAttachment newobj = new ReportAttachment {
            Attachment = data,
            Description = string.Empty,
            Name = Attachment.Title,
            Report = Report,
            ReportId = Report.Id
        };

        var result = this._reportAttachmentRepository.Add(ref newobj);

        Report.ReportAttachments.Add(newobj);

        ModelState.Clear();

        if (!result.Success) {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var msg in result.Messages) {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}", msg.Message));
            }

            return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { message = sb.ToString() } };
        }            

        return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { message = string.Format("{0} uploaded successfully.", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Attachment.FileUpload.FileName)) } };
```

Javascript

```
//Report namespace
InitAttachment: function () {
        jQuery('#AttachmentForm').ajaxForm({
        iframe: true,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            jQuery('#AttachmentForm').block({ message: 'Uploading File... ' });
        },
        success: function (result) {
            jQuery('#AttachmentForm').unblock();
            jQuery('#AttachmentForm').resetForm();
            $.growlUI(null, result.message);

            Editor.EndLoading(false, false, true);
        },

        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
            $("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();
            $.growlUI(null, 'Error uploading file');
        }
    });

//Editor namespace
EndLoading: function (ReloadReportSections, ReloadReferences, ReloadAttachments) {

    //Reload sections
    if (ReloadReportSections)
        jQuery('#LoadReportSectionsForm').submit();

    if (ReloadReferences)
        jQuery('#LoadReferencesForm').submit();

    if (ReloadAttachments) {
        jQuery('#LoadAttachmentsForm').submit();
    }
    //endReload


    Report.InitAttachment();

    //Close the loading dialog
    jQuery('#LoadingWindow').dialog('close');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was that I am calling the update in the wrong location.  In my mind I would imagine that `OnSuccess` would fire before `OnComplete`, but in the MS Ajax model it does not.  `OnSuccess` was being called and it looked like it was affecting the code because it was hitting all the breakpoints I had set, but it must have been hitting the old DOM element before the Replace logic was called.  I cannot seem to find any documentation that talks about the order in which this occurs, but I noticed that when I call `.ajaxForm` from the `AjaxOptions.OnSuccess` property everything works well.  So my suggestion in short:

Use `AjaxOptions.OnSuccess` and `AjaxOptions.OnFailed` to affect the updated DOM but `AjaxOptions.OnComplete` if you need interim logic.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remove the hidden `iframe` (if it exists) in `InitAttachment()` before calling `ajaxForm()`.
It sounds like the target of the file upload form might getting messed up, if the `iframe` from a previous upload is still there.
I've fought with similar issues in `ExtJS`, can't say it's the same though.